# How to Configure MaskedEdit control to accept only alphanumeric values in windows installer?

Tags: wix, windows-installer, wix3.10

I am using WIX Toolset to write an installer(.msi), which accept a product key which is 16 character alphanumeric value in pair of 4 characters separated by each other by `-` e.g. `0000-0000-0000-0000` i am using a MaskedEdit control with following code.

```
<Control Id="Key" Type="MaskedEdit" X="75" Y="84" Width="252" Height="15" Property="ProductKey"  >
      <Text><![CDATA[<&&&&-&&&&-&&&&-&&&&>]]></Text>
    </Control>
```

[image]

It renders on screen as in above picture. But it does not prevent user from entering special characters.
How can I limit accepted character range to alphanumeric only? I get [this article on MaskedEdit](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa369797(v=vs.85).aspx) but can't understand how to use them (what they mean by `alternate` and how can i use `^` to make my inputs in caps?).

Answer (score 1):

Seemingly this is impossible.

The meaning of "alternate" is the following: you may write your own custom action and in this custom action process characters that match & differently than those that match ^.  When user fills in characters in MaskedEdit, & and ^ behave identically.  But after the user presses a button, the custom action may uppercase all characters in places of ^ leaving characters in places of & unchanged.

You may write a custom action which will detect that the input string contains non-alphanumeric characters, and when the user presses the button, warn the user that the input is invalid.

Comment: can you please give me an example of using `^`?

Comment: This will require writing CA - about two pages long.

Comment: that means, there is no significant use of `^`,`?` and others. when we have  to do every thing in CA, right?

Comment: Correct.  Without CA they are all the same.

Comment: one more thing, how can custom action know there was `^`, `&` or `?` used? I have not saved `<&&&&-&&&&-&&&&-&&&&>` in any property.

Comment: CA uses MsiGetProperty / MsiSetProperty functions to retrieve / set property values.  So there should be some convention on what properties are the input and what properties are the output.  For instance, MASK and USERINPUT are input properties and the NORMALIZEDUSERINPUT - the output.  Then you should have been saving your mask in MASK property...